# Apache camel returns multiple exceptions during a route

Tags: java, apache-camel

The code:

```
  from("file://files")
  .split()
  .tokenize("\n")
  .split()
  .method(SplitToken.class, "hashTokens")
  .process(new Processor() {
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> oldSet = (Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>) exchange.getIn().getBody(Set.class);
  StringBuilder fin = new StringBuilder();
  for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry : oldSet) {
fin.append(entry.getValue() + " " + entry.getKey() + "\n");
  }
  exchange.getIn().setBody(fin.toString());
  }
  })
  .to("file://files/Merged.txt");
  }
```

And:

```
public class SplitToken {
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public static Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> hashTokens(final Exchange exchange, @Body List<String> body) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)");
    HashMap<String, Integer> exrate = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    for (String line : body) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
        if (m.find())
            exrate.put(m.group(1), Integer.parseInt(m.group(2)));
    }
    return exrate.entrySet();
}
```

}

The input data consists of serveral files with good names and their respective price tags.

But it just returns so many errors:

```
[org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AnnotationTypeConverterLoader] : Ignoring converter type: org.apache.camel.component.mina.MinaConverter as a dependent class could not be found: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mina/common/ByteBuffer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mina/common/ByteBuffer
```

It returns this error even though I have imported the mina in my pom.xml

And:

```
[org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler] : Redelivery enabled: false on error handler: DefaultErrorHandler[Channel[Splitter[on: BeanExpression[ method: hashTokens] to: Pipeline[[Channel[DelegateSync[main$1$1@5bd7d30f]], Channel[sendTo(Endpoint[file://files/Merged.txt])]]] aggregate: null]]]
]
]


Message History
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------------------------
RouteId              ProcessorId            Processor                                                                        Elapsed (ms)
[route1            ] [route1            ] [file://files                                                               ] [        45]
[route1            ] [split1            ] [split[bean{SplitToken, method=hashTokens}]                                    ] [        19]

Exchange
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------------------------
Exchange[
Id                  ID-ALI-PC-8060-1451994155551-0-4
ExchangePattern     InOnly
Headers             {breadcrumbId=ID-ALI-PC-8060-1451994155551-0-1, CamelFileAbsolute=false, CamelFileAbsolutePath=C:\Users\ali25\Documents\IdeaProjects\files\1.txt, CamelFileContentType=text/plain, CamelFileLastModified=1451993202700, CamelFileLength=111, CamelFileName=1.txt, CamelFileNameConsumed=1.txt, CamelFileNameOnly=1.txt, CamelFileParent=files, CamelFilePath=files\1.txt, CamelFileRelativePath=1.txt, CamelRedelivered=false, CamelRedeliveryCounter=0}
BodyType            String
Body                Good1 450
]

Stacktrace
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------    ----------------------------------------------------------
]
at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1658)
```

And:

```
[org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler] : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-ALI-PC-8060-1451994155551-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-ALI-PC-8060-1451994155551-0-6). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[][Message: Good1 450]
[org.apache.camel.processor.DefaultErrorHandler] : Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-ALI-PC-8060-1451994155551-0-5 on ExchangeId: ID-ALI-PC-8060-1451994155551-0-6). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[][Message: Good1 450]
```

And the error just keeps repeating.
I have no idea why this error has happened since I'm absolutely sure that a set is iteratable, or is it?

EDIT:
contents of pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>apache-camel</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-stream</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mina2</artifactId>
        <version>2.16.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/mina/common/ByteBuffer` - are you perhaps missing a dependency?

Comment: Could you add the relevant parts of your pom.xml?

Comment: org/apache/mina/common/ByteBuffer is from mina 1 and is deprecated, you need to either remove your usage of it, or add the dependency on mina 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the `SplitToken` class.
After first splitter you will get one String (one line of the file), not a list of Strings. And here you receive exception, then Camel trying to convert `String` to `List<String>`, because you have `@Body List<String> body`.

You do not need any Mina dependencies...