# Apache camel aggregate gives exception

Tags: java, apache-camel

Regarding the question: [Apache camel returns multiple exceptions during a route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611301/apache-camel-returns-multiple-exceptions-during-a-route)

Its indicated that I can't get list of strings with split method so I have tried the aggregate method as follows:

```
public class lowestRates implements AggregationStrategy {
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    String oldStr = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    String newStr = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)");
    Matcher m1 = p.matcher(oldStr);
    Matcher m2 = p.matcher(newStr);
    String finalStr = "";
    if(m1.group(2).equalsIgnoreCase(m2.group(2)))
        finalStr = m1.group(1) + Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2)) > Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2)) ? Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2)) : Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2)));
    else
        finalStr = oldStr + "\n" + newStr;
    oldExchange.getIn().setBody(finalStr);
    return oldExchange;
}
```

}

and the new main code:

```
from("file://files")
                    .split()
                    .tokenize("\n")
                    .aggregate(new lowestRates())
                    .body()
                    .completionTimeout(5000)
                    .to("file://files/result.txt")
```

but it gives me:

```
org.apache.camel.CamelExchangeException: Error occurred during aggregation. Exchange[][Message: Good1 450]. Caused by: [java.lang.NullPointerException - null]
```

Now the question is how to write the correct aggregation method cause I fail to see anything done wrong here :(.

Comment: `String oldStr = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);` oldStr will be null for the first message.

Comment: Did you mean the string or the exchange? Also can you suggest a fix for it?

Comment: Please look at my example. I think you can make it better :)

Comment: Interesting, is there anyway that we can solve this problem using the splitter that also does aggregation, or do they have separate usecases?

Comment: You can split file, process each line, or use some kind of filter, after append result to file.

Comment: I think my issue is solved, all I needed was to use(constant(true)) for aggregation match, the solution was simple yet the documentation was so poor so I'm modifying the answer in hope to help the future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String oldStr = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
String newStr = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
```

You need to check strings for null here..
oldStr will be null for the first message.
IMHO you receive exception then trying to parse null String.
And yes, check exchange for null

```
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        return newExchange;
    }
```

UPDATED:
Try like this:

```
public class lowestRates implements AggregationStrategy {
public Exchange aggregate(Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
    if (oldExchange == null) {
        return newExchange;
    }
    if (newExchange.getIn().getBody()!=null){
       Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\w+)\\s(\\d+)");
       String finalStr = ""; 
       String oldStr = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
       String newStr = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
       if (oldStr!=null&&newStr!=null){
       Matcher m1 = p.matcher(oldStr);
       Matcher m2 = p.matcher(newStr);

          if(m1.group(2).equalsIgnoreCase(m2.group(2)))
            finalStr = m1.group(1) + Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2)) > Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2)) ? Integer.parseInt(m2.group(2)) : Integer.parseInt(m1.group(2)));
          else
            finalStr = oldStr + "\n" + newStr;
          }

      oldExchange.getIn().setBody(finalStr);
      }
      return oldExchange;
    }
}
```

Also you need to modify the aggregation as follows,

From:

```
Aggregate(new strategy()).body() //This is where things go wrong
```

To:

```
Aggregate(constant(true), new strategy()).completionFromBatchConsumer()
```

Comment: Unfortunately its wrong answer since the aggregation or the split method have something wrong in them, the oldexchange is ALWAYS NULL.

Comment: Well actually the new answer is the right one, sorry if the comment leads to misunderstanding.